# Cant update data in sql azure with email in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Want to make update data in xamarin forms with email not id, so if the email is null its create new data but when there is email with the same name it will be updating the data. but when i do that i dont know why its shows error message, here is the error code

```
Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).
```

here is my insert and update code

```
     public async Task SaveTaskAsync(Member member)
            {
                if (member.email == null)
                {
                    await _membertable.InsertAsync(member);
                }
                else
                {
                    await _membertable.UpdateAsync(member);
                }
            }
```

and here is my Save/Update button

```
 private async void BtnSave_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                var member = new Member()
                {
                    email = txtemail.Text,
                    fullname = txtfullname.Text,
                    phone = txtphone.Text,
                    birthday = txtdate.Date.ToString(),
                    alamat = txtalamat.Text
                };
                await _membermanager.SaveTaskAsync(member);

                await DisplayAlert("Keterangan", "Data Mu Berhasil disimpan !", "OK");

        }
```

and my table is id, fullname, email, phone, birthday, alamat
Primary Key is in my 'id' , and imake my 'email' as unique key

and here is my Member model

```
namespace KGVC.Models
{
    public class Member
    {
        private string _id;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _email;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
        public string email
        {
            get { return _email; }
            set { _email = value; }
        }

        private string _fullname;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fullname")]
        public string fullname
        {
            get { return _fullname; }
            set { _fullname = value; }
        }

        private string _phone;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phone")]
        public string phone
        {
            get { return _phone; }
            set { _phone = value; }
        }

        private string _birthday;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "birthday")]
        public string birthday
        {
            get { return _birthday; }
            set { _birthday = value; }
        }

        private string _alamat;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alamat")]
        public string alamat
        {
            get { return _alamat; }
            set { _alamat = value; }
        }

        [Version]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

what make me cant update the user data via email, is there anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using the online client against your remote table. For `IMobileServiceTable<T>.InsertAsync`, if you do not specify the `id` property, then the backend would automatically generate it for you. For `IMobileServiceTable<T>.UpdateAsync`, you need to specific the `id` property, or you would get the error response. You could leverage [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when you calling the related methods. Moreover, I would recommend you follow adrian hall's book about [The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/).

Comment: yes you're right , i cant change the primary key either, once i tried make database and set member_id as primary key then i get the error response